# Ansible : How to copy everything from "Files" folders of a specific role

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

i ve an ansible role which looks like this :

```
my-role
├─── files
│       my-file-one
│       my-file-two
│       my-file-...
│       my-file-n
└─── tasks
        main.yml
```

in my **main.yml** , i ve this recursive copy task  , 
and i want to copy all files without the need of listing them manually :

```
- name: copy all files
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: /dest/
  with_items:
    - ????
```

**Suggestions ??**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your `files` directory is flat (i.e., you don't need to worry about recursing directories), you can just use `with_fileglob` to get the list of files:

```
---
- name: copy all files
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: /dest/
  with_fileglob: "files/*"
```

If you need a recursive copy, you can't use `with_fileglob` because it only returns a list of files. You can use the `find` module instead like this:

```
---
- name: list files
  find:
    paths: "{{ role_path }}/files/"
    file_type: any
  register: files

- name: copy files
  copy:
    src: "{{ item.path }}"
    dest: /dest/
  loop: "{{ files.files }}"
```

Comment: This is an old answer. According to docs `with_fileglob` is a local lookup while `find` is a remote lookup so this might not do what you want.

Comment: `find` can work locally if you add `delegate_to: 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 5):

From the [copy module docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html).

> Local path to a file to copy to the remote server.
>   This can be absolute or relative.
>   If path is a directory, it is copied recursively. In this case, if path ends with "/", only inside contents of that directory are copied to destination. Otherwise, if it does not end with "/", the directory itself with all contents is copied.

If you place the files into a subdirectory of the `files` directory (e.g. `my_files`) then you can use `my_files/` as the `src` argument to the `copy` module.

```
my-role
├─── files
|  └───my_files
│         my-file-one
│         my-file-two
│         my-file-...
│         my-file-n
└─── tasks
        main.yml
```

```
- name: copy all files
  copy:
    src: my_files/
    dest: /dest/
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `./` as the `src` argument worked for me. It copies recursively all files and directories from the role `files` directory to target.
This solution does not require to list the files with another task before copying them.

```
---
- name: Copy all role files to target
  copy:
    src: ./
    dest: <destination_dir>
```